# What is $ \mathcal S ( \mathbb R_+ )$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

Does Schartz space of functions defined on positive halfline exists in a meaningful way? How does such functions look like and do you know any applications of such space?